# Histogram of specific rows

Tags: r, histogram, rows

I have a csv that looks similar to the following.

```
Library Parameter1 Parameter2 Parameter3
A       3          6          4
A       4          6          3
A       7          8          9
B       2          10         7
B       4          4          5
B       3          5          4
C       4          6          4
C       6          3          12
C       5          6          8
```

I would like to be able to create a function to create a histogram for a specific library and parameter e.g., histogram of the frequency of Parameter 2 in Library B.

I kind of know how to use the histogram function here's what I have right now.

```
### x = "Parameter"
histogram <- function(x) {hist(filename[[x]], main = "Normalized", 
    xlab = "x", ylab = "Frequency", breaks = ceiling(sqrt(nrow(filename))))}
```

Edit: This is the actual data frame I am working with. It is quite large so I couldn't put the dput in here???

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ivbhc7wyqms0fy/All-Norm.csv?dl=0

(Sorry if I've done anything incorrectly, still very new.)

Comment: what you ask is how to make a histogram on a list type data?

Comment: This is not a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you `dput` your data and add the results to your question in order to make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to subset your data first:

```
sub <- subset(yourdata, Library == "B")$Parameter2
histogram(sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple ggplot I just put together

### Code:

```
dat <- data.frame(Library = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                  Parameter1=c(3,4,7,2,4,3,4,6,5),
                  Parameter2 = c(6,6,8,10,4,5,6,3,6),
                  Parameter3=c(4,3,9,7,5,4,4,12,8))

dat <- data.table::melt(dat,id.vars="Library")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat,aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(Library~variable)
```

### Output:

[image]

Obviously this could be cleaned up a lot, but this is a place to start.